# How does pm2 operates(request redirection and process maintenance) over multiple app server in single threaded environment in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

Our nodejs app use PM2 for vertical scaling of app servers. I have observed following behaviour in case of any error when operated from pm2

1. when uncaught exception happened in any of the app server, it restarts all the app server in that particular cluster.
2. Load balancing is not proper; requests density is always higher in some app then the other(can't see any pattern for distribution).
3. when use node-cache for caching, all app server in cluster creates an individual copy of cached variable thereby increasing memory footprint.